# script# for beginners on vs2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout-2.0, script#

Any knockout.js example on vs2012? And how to setup the script# project to copy the script on asp.net mvc4 project.. adding as reference does not solve in my case and the sample on git does not compile by showing 'command not found.  Error 0009'

Comment: For Getting started with Script#, you should look at this wiki article @ https://github.com/theoutlander/scriptsharp/wiki/Using-the-development-branch. I'll try to work on more examples as I get a chance.

Comment: Another tutorial @ https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/wiki/Creating-your-first-HTML5-Application:-Hello-World

Comment: Created a tutorial on Building a Spreadsheet in Script# @ https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/wiki/Building-a-spreadsheet-in-Script%23-using-HTML5

Answer (score 0):

Using knockout in VS2012 has been simplified. You can create a project using the MVC template in VS2012 (some project templates already have knockoutjs added in the scripts folder. Or you can download it from knockoutjs.com using the link http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/index.html or use the post on msdn

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amar/archive/2012/12/12/hello-world-with-knockout-js-and-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx

the link from John Papa shows how easy is it now to use knockout in VS2012 with the intellisense

http://www.johnpapa.net/knockout-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2012/